# How to bottom align a cell from a row that breaks accross pages in Office Word 2013

Tags: ms-office, word-2010, word-2013

I found an issue in MS Office Word 2010/2013.

When inserting a table that spreads more than one page, if the setting "Allow rows to break accross pages" is enabled, and a row cell is broken acrross two pages, then there is no way to bottom align any other column. The columns in the same row are aligning to the bottom of the part of the row in page 1 instead bottom aligning to the bottom of the row in page 2.

I would need the bottom aligned cells printed on page 2. 
Does anybody know a work around for this?

Please see the attached image that illustrates the issue that I am trying to fix:

[image: Cell content not moving to the next page]